# СМС уведомление при неработающем сайте

Tags: сервер, уведомления

Бывает такое, что падает сервер (по каким-либо причинам). Не всегда находишься за компьютером и не имеешь возможность вовремя заметить это.

Возможно есть какие-либо инструменты дополнительного оповещения о неработающем сайте, например СМС-уведомление? Или еще что-нибудь "офлайновое".

Comment: повесь на aws (любой на твой выбор) скрипт ping ip  и при отрицательном результате с помощью api sms***.*** (любой на твой выбор)  отправляй себе смс)

Comment: В любой нормальной системе мониторинга подобная фича должна быть встроена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стыдно признаться, но я и не заметил галочку SMS-сообщение в настройках уведомлений о проблемах с сайтом в Яндекс.Метрике)